# NS_ENUM error when declared before class instance variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

Example .h file:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject


typedef NS_ENUM(int, myType) {
    Something,
    SomethingElse,
    SomethingElseElse,
    YetAnotherSomethingElse
};

{ //Error On This Line: Expected Identifier or '('

    int aInstanceVariable;

}


//Some Methods go here
@end
```

Why am I getting that error (see the comment in the code above)? It works fine when below the class instance variable declaration, but I would like to use it as the type for one of my instance variables.

Comment: Did you try putting it above the @interface block?

Comment: @CarlVeazey No I didn't. That fixed it. Thanks. Wanna make a quick answer on my question or should I?

Comment: Was trying to find some reference on exactly what's legal after @interface but couldn't. Go ahead and self answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CarlVeazey, I discovered that the answer was simple: Move the `typedef` declaration to above `@interface`. The reason for this is that types cannot be owned by a class or an instance of a class, and therefore cannot be in the interface for a class.